# How Can I make a Macro public when I push the buttom in a Customize Ribbon?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel that It has a customize Ribbon when I push this buttom, execute a code (e.g. show a msgbox). I want all excel file on my computer have this Customize Ribbon and when it push, execute the same code. The problem is when I close the excel that has this Macro, and, I open other new file excel and push this customize Ribbon, the excel file that has the Macro will  open. I don´t want happens this, I would like to put the Macro Code in all Excel files, and when I push the button, the code is execute without open the Excel file with the Macro. How Do I make this?[image]

Comment: You need to convert it to an Add-In and then install it so that it is available all the time. Search google on how to create Excel Add-Ins

Comment: Another option would be copying all those macros and menu into your [personal macros workbook](https://trumpexcel.com/personal-macro-workbook/), so it ill be available anytime you open excel files **in that computer**